# Retrieving More Than 12 Months of Historical Metrics Using Google Ads API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm currently using the Google Ads API to fetch historical metrics for specific keywords. By default, the API provides data for the last 12 months. However, I'm interested in retrieving data for a longer period, say 24 months or more. Is there a way to specify a date range or retrieve data for more than 12 months using the Google Ads API? If not, are there any workarounds to achieve this? The sample code is here:https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/keyword-planning/generate-historical-metrics

```
def main(client, customer_id):
    """The main method that creates all necessary entities for the example.

    Args:
        client: an initialized GoogleAdsClient instance.
        customer_id: a client customer ID.
    """
    generate_historical_metrics(client, customer_id)


def generate_historical_metrics(client, customer_id):
    """Generates historical metrics and prints the results.

    Args:
        client: an initialized GoogleAdsClient instance.
        customer_id: a client customer ID.
    """
    googleads_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")
    keyword_plan_idea_service = client.get_service("KeywordPlanIdeaService")
    request = client.get_type("GenerateKeywordHistoricalMetricsRequest")
    request.customer_id = customer_id
    request.keywords = ["mars cruise", "cheap cruise", "jupiter cruise"]
    # Geo target constant 2840 is for USA.
    request.geo_target_constants.append(
        googleads_service.geo_target_constant_path("2840")
    )
    request.keyword_plan_network = (
        client.enums.KeywordPlanNetworkEnum.GOOGLE_SEARCH
    )
    # Language criteria 1000 is for English. For the list of language criteria
    # IDs, see:
    # https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/data/codes-formats#languages
    request.language = googleads_service.language_constant_path("1000")

    response = keyword_plan_idea_service.generate_keyword_historical_metrics(
        request=request
    )

    for result in response.results:
        metrics = result.keyword_metrics
        # These metrics include those for both the search query and any variants
        # included in the response.
        print(
            f"The search query '{result.text}' (and the following variants: "
            f"'{result.close_variants if result.close_variants else 'None'}'), "
            "generated the following historical metrics:\n"
        )

        # Approximate number of monthly searches on this query averaged for the
        # past 12 months.
        print(f"\tApproximate monthly searches: {metrics.avg_monthly_searches}")

        # The competition level for this search query.
        print(f"\tCompetition level: {metrics.competition}")

        # The competition index for the query in the range [0, 100]. This shows
        # how competitive ad placement is for a keyword. The level of
        # competition from 0-100 is determined by the number of ad slots filled
        # divided by the total number of ad slots available. If not enough data
        # is available, undef will be returned.
        print(f"\tCompetition index: {metrics.competition_index}")

        # Top of page bid low range (20th percentile) in micros for the keyword.
        print(
            f"\tTop of page bid low range: {metrics.low_top_of_page_bid_micros}"
        )

        # Top of page bid high range (80th percentile) in micros for the
        # keyword.
        print(
            "\tTop of page bid high range: "
            f"{metrics.high_top_of_page_bid_micros}"
        )

        # Approximate number of searches on this query for the past twelve
        # months.
        for month in metrics.monthly_search_volumes:
            print(
                f"\tApproximately {month.monthly_searches} searches in "
                f"{month.month.name}, {month.year}"
            )
```